# Trouble Binding Selected Items from ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, listbox

I'm having a moment.  I can't seem to get the selected items from a `ListBox` to be bound in a parameter to the action method that handles the `post` event.

`Model` is of type `SystemRoleList`:

```
public class SystemRoleList {
    public IEnumerable<SystemRole> List { get; set; }
}
```

`SystemRole` is defined as:

```
public class SystemRole {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

This code generates the `ListBox`:

```
<%: this.Html.ListBox("Roles", new SelectList(Model.List, "Id", "Name")) %>
```

The action method receiving the selected items is set up like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateSystemRoles(Int32[] roles) {
    // do something with the results....
}
```

The trouble is that `roles` is always `null`.  I've tried using other data types - `string[]`, `ICollection<int>`, and so on.  I can see the values in the `Request.Form` collection if I do `Request.Form["Roles[]"]`.  Typical values might be `1,3,4` if I selected those items from the `ListBox`.

How can I name either the `ListBox` or my parameter so that MVC will automatically bind the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, the following works perfectly fine for me.

Model:

```
public class SystemRoleList
{
    public IEnumerable<SystemRole> List { get; set; }
}

public class SystemRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SystemRoleList
        {
            List = new[]
            {
                new SystemRole { Id = 1, Name = "role 1" },
                new SystemRole { Id = 2, Name = "role 2" },
                new SystemRole { Id = 3, Name = "role 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int[] roles)
    {
        return Content("thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Controllers.SystemRoleList>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.ListBox("Roles", new SelectList(Model.List, "Id", "Name")) %>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

This being said I would use the strongly typed version of the `ListBox` helper, like this:

Model:

```
public class SystemRoleList
{
    public int[] Roles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SystemRole> List { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SystemRoleList
        {
            List = new[]
            {
                new SystemRole { Id = 1, Name = "role 1" },
                new SystemRole { Id = 2, Name = "role 2" },
                new SystemRole { Id = 3, Name = "role 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SystemRoleList model)
    {
        return Content("thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Controllers.SystemRoleList>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.ListBoxFor(x => x., new SelectList(Model.List, "Id", "Name")) %>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What does your `Request.Form` collection look like? Do you have multiple entries for `roles` or are they `roles[]` instead?

Comment: @Yuck, `Request.Form["Roles"] = "1,2"` and `Request.Form["Roles[]"] = null`. I have multiple entries for roles: `Roles=1&Roles=3`.

Comment: So I think that's the problem - my form values include `roles[]` and not `roles`. This is being used in a partial view so something higher up is probably interfering and causing it to post that way instead. Going to guess it's Telerik's MVC extensions at this point. Thanks for your help.